# change div/link class onclick with js - problems

Tags: javascript, class, onclick

Figured out how to change the class of a div/link/whatever onclick with JS. Here's a quick demo: http://nerdi.net/classchangetest.html

Now what I'm trying to figure out is how I can revert the previously clicked link to it's old class (or "deactivate") when clicking a new link.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeCssClass(navlink)
{
    var links=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i=0, n=links.length; i<n; i++)
    {
         links[i].className='redText';
    }
    document.getElementById(navlink).className = 'blueText';
}
```

With this code all links will be red and lust clicked will be blue.

I hope it will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeCssClass(ele, add_class) {
    // if add_class is not passed, revert
    // to old className (if present)
    if (typeof add_class == 'undefined') {
        ele.className = typeof ele._prevClassName != 'undefined' ? ele._prevClassName : '';
    } else {
        ele._prevClassName = ele.className || '';
        ele.className = add_class;
    }
}
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zn7BL/

Use it:

```
// add "withClass"
changeCssClass(document.getElementById('test'), 'withClass');

// revert to original
changeCssClass(document.getElementById('test'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a much better to post your code here, it makes it easier for those reading the question and for others searching later. Linked examples are unreliable and likely won't persist for long.

Copying from the link (and formatting for posting):

```
<style type="text/css">
.redText, .blueText { font-family: Arial; }
.redText  { color : red;  } 
.blueText { color : blue; }
</style>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

The language attribute has been deprecated for a very long time, it should not be used. The type attribute is required, so keep that.

```
    function changeCssClass(navlink)
```

The HTML class attribute is not sepecifically for CSS, it is used to group elements. A better name might be *changeClassName*.

```
    {
        if(document.getElementById(navlink).className=='redText')
        {
            document.getElementById(navlink).className = 'blueText';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(navlink).className = 'redText';
        }
    }

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="changeCssClass('navlink')" id="navlink" class="redText">Link 1</a><br><br>
```

When called, the function associated with an inline listener will have its *this* keyword set to the element, so you can call the function as:

```
<a ... onclick="changeCssClass(this);" ...>
```

Then you don't have to pass the ID and you don't need *getElementById* in the function.

You might consider a function that "toggles" the class: adding it if it's not present, or removed if it is. You'll need to write some small functions like *hasClass*, *addClass* and *removeClass*, then your listener can be:

```
function toggleClass(el, className) {
  if (hasClass(el, className) {
    removeClass(el, className);
  } else {
    addClass(el, className);
  }
}
```

Then give your links a default style using a style rule (i.e. apply the *redText* style to all links), then just add and remove the *blueText* class.

You might also consider putting a single function on a parent of the links to handle clicks from A elements — i.e. event delegation.